# Why can't they get to Geonosis in time if it is less than parsec away?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Padme responds to a holographic message by Obi Wan:

> Padme: They'll never get there in time to save him. They have to come
> halfway across the galaxy. Look. **Geonosis is less than a parsec away**.

Why can't they get to Geonosis in time if it is less than parsec away?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Padme is talking about the other Jedi, led by Mace Windu, who she was just talking to previously:

> MACE WINDU We will deal with Count Dooku. The most important thing for you, Anakin, is to stay where you are. Protect the Senator at all costs. That is your priority.
>
> ANAKIN Understood, Master.

Whereas Padme is saying that *she and Anakin* are only a parsec away from Geonosis, and they *can* get there in time.  In the next lines she indicates that despite the orders from Windu she is prepared to go personally to Geonosis to save Obi-Wan.

> PADME Annie, are you just going to sit here and let him die?? He's your friend... your mentor...
>
> ANAKIN ...He's like my father, but you heard Master Windu. He gave me strict orders to stay here.
>
> PADME He gave you strict orders to protect me...
>
> PADME pulls her hand free and flicks more switches. The engines fire.
>
> PADME (continuing) ...and I'm going to save Obi-Wan. So if you plan to protect me, you will have to come along.

Comment: I always thought that moment was hilarious

Comment: @Firestryke - one of the few good character moments between those two

Comment: Also famous for Amidala pressing the same button to transmit the message to the Jedi council **AND** minutes later to view a map locating Geonosis.

Comment: @user10191234: That’s just good adaptive interface design!